# Accurate PWM pulse length with PIGPIO

Tags: gpio, pwm, pigpio, radio, timekeeping

EDIT: Added details/clarity

I’m using the PIGPIO library on an RPi4, using the monitor_pwm/read_pwm example to get the time signal from the WWVB AM radio broadcast. (http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/code/monitor_py.zip)

I’m using the PIGPIO callback function to get a reading every 10ms. If I just print out a counter in the callback function, this seems work properly, but if I then also read the PWM pulse I only seem to get readings every so often.

Main program:

```py
    pi = pigpio.pi()
    p = read_pwm.reader(pi, PWM_GPIO)
    pi.set_watchdog(PWM_GPIO, 10) # run every 10ms
    decode_cb = pi.callback(
        PWM_GPIO, pigpio.FALLING_EDGE, decode_pulse)
```

decode_pulse() snippet:

```py
    f = p.frequency()
    pw = p.pulse_width()
    dc = p.duty_cycle()
    pulseWidth = pw / 1000

    sample_counter -= 1

    print(f, pulseWidth, dc)
    return
```

Per this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WWVB#Amplitude-modulated_time_code
[image]

I should be seeing pulses in the ranges of 200ms, 500ms and 800ms - with ~800ms once every 10 seconds. However it looks the results I'm seeing are 800 for 3 or 4 seconds in a row. I know the signal the pi reading is correct because my wall clock gets set properly, and I used piscope to confirm/decode the signal the GPIO is receiving.

I’m wondering if I’m not using something correctly in the PIGPIO or something. Perhaps callback() is not the right tool? I'm not really sure.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - I added some clarity that will hopefully help explain things better.

Comment: If you want help post the **code you used** (or better a minimal program which demonstrates the problem) and any diagnostics - code snippets are meaningless. NOTE printing ANYTHING in a callback is poor coding practice. Callbacks should be as short as possible.

Comment: Are you familiar with the pigpio library? I’m printing as debug, not as good practice of permanent long running code. There is enough information in what I posted to see the execution path. It’s literally setting up the library and a callback that runs a few lines of code and returns. Chiding doesn’t really help here.